# get not working for multiple entry widget in tkinter

Tags: python, get, tkinter

I need to get 3 values from entry and pass it as argument for another function to search the entered content. But I am unable to get the values. Here is my code.

```
def read_files():
    input=entry1.get()
    with open(input, newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for line in spamreader:
            contents.append(line)

    entries = []
    val=["no","num2","date"]
    for i in range(3):
        label = Label(f2, text=val[i])
        label.grid(row=i, column=0)
        entry = Entry(f2, width=25)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
        entries.append(entry.get())
    button1 = ttk.Button(f2, text="Search", command=search(**pass the get value here**))
    button1.grid(row=4, column=0)
    button2 = ttk.Button(f2, text="Quit")
    button2.grid(row=4, column=1)
    button2.bind ('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: exit())



main = Tk()
main.title("SEARCH")
main.grid()
#main.geometry('640x480')

frame1 = ttk.Frame(main, height=200, width=200)
frame1.grid()
f2 = Frame(main, height=300, width = 300)
f2.grid()
entry1 = Entry(frame1, width=30)
entry1.pack()

button1 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="File", command=read_files)
button1.pack()
#button1.bind ('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: progressbar.start())

button2 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Quit")
button2.pack()
button2.bind ('<ButtonPress>', lambda e: exit())

frame2 = ttk.Frame(main, height=100, width=100)
frame2.grid()
listbox = Listbox(frame2, height=100, width=100)
listbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

What is the error here. and how do i get the values from the entry widget

Comment: *What is the error here?* You tell me.  What are you trying to do, what is it doing, what do you expect?

Comment: I am not able to get value from entry widget. which need to be paased to another function as arguement! but entries[] is null. @jedwards

Comment: I mean, there are a lot of problems with this, but you may be able to skirt by with moving `entries = []` outside of the function.

Comment: tried and still not working @jedwards

Comment: You're appending `entry.get()` to `entries` right after you have created `entry`, so at this time, `entry.get()` returns an empty string because the user hasn't typed anything in `entry` yet. Therefore, `entries` is a list of empty strings.

Comment: How can i fix it? @fhdrsdg

Comment: You need to save the references to the Entry widgets (possibly in a list), then create a callback function for the search button and wait with calling `get()` until in that callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, you're appending `entry.get()` to `entries` right after you have created `entry`, so at this time, `entry.get()` returns an empty string because the user hasn't typed anything in `entry` yet. Therefore, `entries` is a list of empty strings.

You need to save the references to the Entry widgets (possibly in a list), then create a callback function for the search button and wait with calling `get()` until in that callback function like in the code snippet below

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def search():
    for entry in entries:
        print entry.get()

f2 = Tk()
entries = []
val=["no","num2","date"]

for i in range(3):
    label = Label(f2, text=val[i])
    label.grid(row=i, column=0)
    entry = Entry(f2, width=25)
    entry.grid(row=i, column=1)
    entries.append(entry)

button1 = ttk.Button(f2, text="Search", command=search)
button1.grid(row=4, column=0)

f2.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks. Your script works completely fine. But it doesnot work when i integrate in my script!

Comment: "does not work" does not provide enough details for me to be able to help you.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please check now? @fhdrsdg

Comment: What's the error you are getting? I guess that it's about `entries` not being defined in `searching`, but it would help if you could post the error.

Comment: Ok, first of all, `command=searching()` should be `command=searching`.

Comment: Also, you can't really expect that people write solutions for you that can be copy-pasted into your code and work. Answers you get are usually ideas about how something can be done, with an example use. If you understand the idea, the you should be able to rework any example to fit into your own code.